# Changing the action link on DXA search box

Tags: dxa, search

When using the DXA search module how can I change the 'action' value in the DXA header search box?

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="http://testsite.com/search" method="get">
    . . .
</form>
```

The URL of my site is testsite.co.uk but the link is being resolved to testsite.com.

I tried adding "ResultsLink" to the 'Search configuration' component but it has no affect.

Thanks all

Comment: What is mentioned in your `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` and in your `cd_link_conf.xml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value is obtained from the cd_link_conf.xml file in the /bin/config folder of your DXA website.

Don't forget to recycle your app pool to pick up the new config changes.

Comment: the DXA installer sets the URL you supplied at installation time in the `cd_link_conf.xml` file. Personally I always remove all Publication references from the `cd_link_conf.xml` since then links remain relative to the URL you are browsing, rather than an absolute one.

Comment: I think in DXA 1.1 if you want to use RSS feed you need the entries in cd_link_conf, otherwise the feed will have relative URLs